# FlaskWTF multiple forms same page with 1 submit button

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to create something in which a user can add a chosen amount of people to a database. The only thing (right now) that is asked is the persons name.

I create this form by doing the following:

```
        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('add_person') }}">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            {% for i in range(0, amount) %}
                {{ form.plafond.label }}
                {{ form.plafond }}
                </br>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

and:

```
class new_person(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name')
```

How can I get the individual data the person has put in each field?

Comment: You need to add it to the formr and then cll sth like object.data.varname

Comment: @E.Serra Do you in the flask app.py to add form.plafond.data? This will only return the value of the first field filled in.

Comment: No in the clases definitivo for the for. Dont have access to my latop now Will check when i can but your we forma should matcj the form clases iirc

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those fields in the form, assuming they are strings (change the data type for the one you use)

```
class new_person(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name')
    csrf_token =StringField('csrf')
```

Then on submit you access it by (in you add_person method):

```
form = new_person()
form.csrf.data # This will give you the csrf data
```